# Cannot jump to the source line from Performance tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In performance tab of devtools, under Call Tree (or Bottom Up) in the very right column are links to the line in the source code, where the given entry originated from. However when I click it nothing happens. Shouldn't it redirect me to the appropriate place in the source code? Also it seems to be not respecting source maps.

[image: call tree of performance tab in devtools]

Is it how it works at the moment? Or I have a flaw in my setup somewhere?

Comment: Can confirm, it looks like a link but nothing happens.

Comment: Experiencing the same on linux with react create app, did you solve this?

Comment: Never tried again after this actually :'/

Comment: This is absolutely insane level of granularity of performance on this guys article: https://calibreapp.com/blog/react-performance-profiling-optimization, I assume this is what we both want to get to?